# GeoCoordinateWatcher and timeout

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am new to Windows Phone 8 development and I'm trying to use the **GeoCoordinateWatcher** class to easily get the latitude and longitude of the user.

My problem is that I want to manage a timeout (the user will be able to customize its value).

I thought the "TryStart(...)" method would help me to do that, but:

```
tryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); => The watcher starts after 10sec
tryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); => The watcher starts after 2sec
```

This method is, for me, pointless as I want the GeoCoordinateWatcher to start immediately (so I'm using the basic method "Start()", but I also want to return an exception like "The timeout has expired" if it takes more than *xxx* seconds to return coordinates.

Is there an easy way to do that ? Do I have to create a timer or something like that ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Phone 8, you should use Geolocation API which is a part of Windows Phone Runtime
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.getgeopositionasync.aspx

This provides a simple / easy way to get location without mucking around.

You might want to go through my verbose blog post on possible issues.
http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/geolocator-and-movementthreshold-wpdev-win8dev/

Comment: The project is in stand by; will try your solution later, but thanks for the answer